# Using full name when booking a flight ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets, japan

I bought a flight ticket from Budapest to Tokyo Narita from Emirates, and I used my full name for it.

My full name is Wade Tyler Edward Johnson and on Emirates' website Wade appears most of the time, except when using Mr. then it's Mr. Johnson.

But if I want to modify my booking it states my name as Wadetyleredward Johnson.

Would this be a problem?

If it makes a difference, I have been to Japan before, and have NOT overstayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem. It is quite common for airline booking systems to mangle names in this way, and far worse, depending on where the information is presented. Airline staff are quite used to this and will not have any objection.

Comment: I would like to another question; my passport is a bit worn out, not damaged, but the front page that has all my details is intact, and it's also biometric. Is it fine or should I change it? It has three years left before it expires.

Comment: @WadeTyler You should probably post that as a new question, perhaps with a picture (with your personal information blacked out). I'd broadly say that normal wear is expected, damage is not, but you're really best posting a new question and getting advice from everyone.

Comment: I will post a new question, but I can't take pictures of it, it's not mine actually, it's a friend's. But I can accurately describe it since she told me a lot about it.